# How to set maxResults in spring CloudVisionTemplate | Google Vision API Java

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-platform, google-vision, vision-api

I am using Spring org.springframework.cloud.gcp.vision.CloudVisionTemplate for detecing labels in an image using Google Vision API like below:

```
AnnotateImageResponse annotateImageResponse = cloudVisionTemplate.analyzeImage(imageResource,
                Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION);
        annotationList = annotateImageResponse.getLabelAnnotationsList();
```

By default it seems like, it only fetches 10 results, but we need all the labels detected. I went through the [Google API doc](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/Feature) and it mentions about a parameter `maxResults`.

But this is described using REST API. I am looking how to set this `maxResults` using spring `CloudVisionTemplate` in Java or Google Vision Java SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found this limit of 10 result in any documentation, however I tested  it on [Try this API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/labels?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22requests%22%3A%5B%7B%22features%22%3A%5B%7B%22maxResults%22%3A5%2C%22type%22%3A%22LABEL_DETECTION%22%7D%5D%2C%22image%22%3A%7B%22source%22%3A%7B%22imageUri%22%3A%22gs%3A%2F%2Fcloud-samples-data%2Fvision%2Flabel%2Fsetagaya.jpeg%22%7D%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D#try_it) in the documentation. When I removed `"maxResults": 5,` from the request, it indeed returned 10 result. I tired with `"maxResults": 100` and returned more than 30 results.

In Java API it's seems to be possible, but not using `CloudVisionTemplate`. It's implementation is available on [github](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/6c95a16f7e6ad95404b4f992b5f46340e831e5cb/spring-cloud-gcp-vision/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/vision/CloudVisionTemplate.java) and it is not extremely sophisticated... We can see there that `Feature` is build only with type from  list provided as parameter (in line [128](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/6c95a16f7e6ad95404b4f992b5f46340e831e5cb/spring-cloud-gcp-vision/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/vision/CloudVisionTemplate.java#L128)):

```
Feature.newBuilder().setType(featureType).build()
```

Now in Java API reference we may find that this Feature.builder contains [method](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-vision/latest/com/google/cloud/vision/v1/Feature.Builder.html#setMaxResults-int-) `setMaxResults`. So you can customize `cloudVisionTemplate` or create your own code with something like:

```
Feature.newBuilder().setType(Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION).setMaxResults(100).build()
```

Unfortunately I do not have environment to test this. If you will try please share the result. I don't think it will be possible to set unlimited number as max, but probably you are able to choose number large enough.

Comment: @vitooh - Yes, this way we solved it, but it is surprising that Spring does not have support for setting max_results parameter.